# Increae a version's last part

Tags: ruby

What is the best way to increase the last part of a version by 1 (without the use of libraries).

Examples:

`Gem::Version.new("2.0.31")` to `Gem::Version.new("2.0.32")`
`Gem::Version.new("2.0.3.0")` to `Gem::Version.new("2.0.3.1")`

If the output is a string, that's ok too

Comment: split by `.`, take the `last`, turn it into an integer with `to_i`, increment, join the parts again.  It's not really clear what you mean by "without the use of libraries". `Gem::Version` is a library, are you trying to remove that code, and just use strings?

Comment: I think your "without the use of libraries" restriction is too restrictive. You are going to need to use at least either `Gem::Version#to_s` or `Gem::Version#version` from the RubyGems library to even know what the *current* version is, before you increase it. (And of course, without the core library, you don't even get `String` or `Integer`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Gem::Version#segments`:

```
Gem::Version.new("2.0.31").
  segments.
  dup.
  tap { |segments| segments.push(segments.pop.succ) }.
  join('.')
#⇒ "2.0.32"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a helper method I've used as part of `rake` tasks before, for version bumping.

Feel free to extend it as per your needs - e.g. if you want to add a forth number; or support versions named `alpha-x` or `pre-x`; or support an option for 'bump the last digit' (regardless of how many digits there are).

However, I'd be inclined not to support a 'bump the last digit' option, as this is quite ambiguous.

```
def bump(version, type)
  major, minor, patch = version.split('.').map(&:to_i)

  bumped = case type
           when :major
             [major + 1, 0, 0]
           when :minor
             [major, minor + 1, 0]
           when :patch
             [major, minor, patch + 1]
           else
             raise "Don't know how to bump for #{type}"
           end 
  bumped.join('.')
end


bump("2.1.31", :patch) #=> "2.1.32"
bump("2.1.31", :minor) #=> "2.2.0"
bump("2.1.31", :major) #=> "3.0.0"
```

Comment: Your `bump("2.1.31", :minor)` is implemented natively by `Gem::Version#bump`.

Comment: I'm not using `Gem::Version`, though. This is dealing with plain old strings. For example, you can use this for NPM package versions.

Comment: I’d better commit a suicide rather than _dealing with NPM_ :)